# Python: Insert string (colon) in between HEX

Tags: python

I plan to insert string (colon) in between HEX in Python, i.e;

before: AABBCCDDEEFF112233
after: AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF:11:22:33

Can anybody here shed some light on how to achieve it.

Regards,

Comment: Have you tried solving your problem yourself before asking others to do it for you?

Comment: Use the grouper itertools recipe: http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes and then join on `":"`. Done.

Comment: Break it up into 2 character strings and then `':'.join(pieces)`.

Comment: `s = "AABBCCDDEEFF112233"\n"".join([(c if idx % 2 == 0 else c + ":") for c, idx in zip(s, range(0, len(s)))]).rstrip(":")`

Comment: if the original input is a bytestring (e.g., from integer), then `binascii.hexlify(bytesring, ':')` could be used, to insert colon into the hex representation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is here: [Pythonic way to insert every 2 elements in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258573/pythonic-way-to-insert-every-2-elements-in-a-string)

You could also use a step i.e. `str[::x]` to loop over every 2 characters to achieve this result.

```
myStr = 'AABBCCDDEEFF112233'
print ':'.join(myStr[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(myStr), 2))
```

Comment: You shouldn't name variables something that collides with a built-in.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the name. Thanks.