# how to insert characters in defined places in a python string?

Tags: python, string

what is the pythonic efficient way to insert a character every n-characters in a string? for example

```
ins("aabbccdd", 2, "-") => "aa-bb-cc-dd"
```

is there a way to do this with iterators?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pythonic way to insert every 2 elements in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258573/pythonic-way-to-insert-every-2-elements-in-a-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `str.join` `i` length chunks of `s`:

```
s = "aabbccdd"
i = 2
print("-".join([s[j:j+i] for j in range(0,len(s),i)]))
aa-bb-cc-dd
```

Comment: `'-'.join(s[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2))` can eliminate the `i = 2`.

Comment: @I'L'I I used i so the OP can choose the chunk size