# One-liner python script to separate a string with comma for every 2 characters

Tags: python

I made below Perl one-liner to separate a string, e.g. 080041ba, with comma for every 2 characters .
I am wondering is there any Python one-liner, at least not spanning many lines, to achieve the same goal?

```
$ perl -e 'print((join ",","080041ba"=~/../g),"\n")'
08,00,41,ba
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
$ python -c 'import re; print re.sub("(..)(?!$)", r"\1,", "080041ba")'
08,00,41,ba
```

Comment: Thanks, but why did you use `r"\1,"` rather than `"\1,"` ? Is there any difference?

Comment: @Zii yes because in `raw string literals` the `\` is taken just as is and not as a escape sequence (unless it comes right before a quote that would otherwise terminate the literal). Then if you try with `"\1,"` instead you would replace each two characters by the characters `"\x01,"` which is not what you want. You can take a look at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l)

Comment: @Zii yes because in `raw string literals` the \ is taken just as is and not as a escape sequence (unless it comes right before a quote that would otherwise terminate the literal). Then if you try with "\1," instead you would replace each two characters by the characters "\x01," which is not what you want. You can take a look at [what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l)

Answer (score 1):

[Pythonic way to insert every 2 elements in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258573/pythonic-way-to-insert-every-2-elements-in-a-string)

```
','.join(a+b for a,b in zip(s[::2], s[1::2]))
```

To declare string s as part of the line, just add s = "..."; e.g.:

```
s = "080041ba"; ','.join(a+b for a,b in zip(s[::2], s[1::2]))
```

Comment: This is very Pythonic. Thanks.

Comment: Sure!  I guess I should mention that s should be declared as a string, which you can do inline