# Python, Add + between every third letter

Tags: python

I want be able to add a plus sign (+) for every third letter. 
For instance,

sequence = ABCDEF

ABC + DEF

I've tried Str.join and it works sorta, but I want it to add a plus sign every third letter.

This is what I have so far.

```
s = sequence
a = (' + '.join(s))
```

Comment: You could use a chunking solution from here: [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/312443/4518341) Most of them work on any sequence including strings.

Comment: You  might want to have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258573/pythonic-way-to-insert-every-2-elements-in-a-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
''.join([your_string[n] if n%3 != 2 else your_string[n]+' + ' for n in range(len(your_string))])
```

A bit more complicated than the previous answer, but basically it creates a string where every character is the same as the original string, except for every third one, to which it gets added `' + '`.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```
'+'.join(sequence[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(sequence),3))
```

Basically what this does is, first, get a sequence of numbers at indices at multiples of 3 using range: `range(0,len(sequence),3)`

Next, find substrings of length 3 starting from every index: `[sequence[i, i+3] for i in range...]`

Finally, join these substrings with a '+': `'+'.join(...)`

Hope this helps.

Comment: you don't need the list casting.